# Why don't we need to perform modulo operation on every operands in Fast Power algorithm?

Tags: c++, math, modular-arithmetic

Today I practiced with a puzzle "fast power", which used a formula: 
`(a * b) % p = (a % p * b % p) % p` to calculate `(a^n)%p`, something like that: `2^31 % 3 = 2`

However, I am so confused when I found the answer used `((temp * temp) % b * a) % b;` to solved situation when n is odd, like `2^3`

(temp is `(temp * temp) % b * a` recursively or `(temp * temp) % b`).

Should not it be `((temp * temp) % b * a%b) % b`?

Since according to this formula, everything should `%b` before times together.

Comment: How is this a c++ question ??

Comment: Can not u see there are one line code in this question? Please also check the answer below.

Comment: No ! Certainly, not that I can compile  ! ...  The answer below is a good example that you should follow to format your question ..

Comment: Alright.. I will keep that in mind. Thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should not it be `((temp * temp) % b * a % b) % b`?

No. For `a`, if you know beforehand that `a` won't overflow(a is smaller than b), you don't have to mod it.

The idea is [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) works for addition and multiplication.
Operation like `(a + b) % M = (a % M + b % M) % M` and `(a * b) % M = (a % M * b % M) % M` are generally performed to avoid overflow of `(a * b)` and `(a + b)` and keep the value under certain range.

Example:

```
const int Mod = 7;
int a = 13;
int b = 12;
int b = b % Mod; // b now contains 5 which is certainly smaller than Mod

int x = (a % Mod * b) % Mod; // you won't need to mod b again if you know beforehand b is smaller than Mod
```

### Update

C++ implementation of power function:

```
#define MOD 1000000007
// assuming x and n both be positive and initially smaller than Mod
int power(int x, int n) {
    if(n == 0) return x;
    int half = power(x, n / 2) % Mod;
    int ret = (half * half) % Mod; // you didn't need to do (half % Mod * half % Mod) % Mod because you already know half is smaller than Mod and won't overflow. 
                                   // Modulas being performed on the multiplied output, so now ret will be smaller than Mod
    if(n & 1) {
        ret = (ret * x) % Mod; // you didn't need to do (ret % Mod * x % Mod) % Mod
                               // because you already know ret and x is smaller than Mod
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Mod is an expensive operation. So you should avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: WOW amazing! So You mean one single number actually not necessary needed to do % operation? Because it seems in the formula every number does % operation